# Protocol Extension Overriding a Built in Class member function

Tags: ios, swift

```
protocol PushNotification {
   func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings)
}

extension PushNotification where Self:AppDelegate {
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
        print("Register for Push Notifications Successful")
    }
}
```

I am trying to have my app delegate instead of calling its own

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings)
```

Call the extension but it does not appear to work ? 
Is this even possible ? in swift 2.3 ? or swift 3 ?

Expected Behaviors

So when I write

```
let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(
            forTypes: [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

It should call

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings)
```

which belongs to the app delegate which I would normally have to override in the app delegate.

I am expecting it to call my protocol extension instead. Here is app delegate

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, AWSDKDelegate, PushNotification {
// Could this function be called from my protocol extension instead?
// Rather than me overriding this function ?
  //    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
//        print("Register for Push Notifications Successful")
//    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify as to what's happening, and what you wish to happen?

Comment: So when I call   

let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(
            forTypes: [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()



It should call

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) which belongs to the app delegate which I would normally have to override in the app delegate.

but my protocol extension isn't called.

Comment: Am expected to understand something out of that?

Comment: Sorry stack overflow is not behaving the way I want just a second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extensions to protocols provide default implementations of methods. Any conforming type that implements that method as well will override the extension's implementation.

Comment: yeah I understand that, will it cover the case above?  where I want app delegate to choose the protocol extension implementation ?

Comment: `AppDelegate` doesn't choose anything. If `AppDelegate` implements the method, it'll override the default implementation, and that's what will be called. If you want to use the default implementation, then don't implement an override of the method in your `AppDelegate`

Comment: Can I get the Protocol Extension to override that function ?

Comment: Protocol Extensions can't "override" methods, but they can provide default implementations, such as what you already have.

Comment: Ahhh ... well that sucks I was hoping to remove some boiler plate

Comment: And what boiler plate is that?

Comment: func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {

 }

When I have push notifications for an app I just want the protocol extension to override that function and implement it with my default implementation, however there are a couple of more functions not just this one around 4 of them which generally do the same thing for almost all apps I work with, that are apart of app delegate

Comment: func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError)
    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128211/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-george-host).

Comment: Yeah I left a  message in chat not sure if it is clear

Comment: Yeah its not possible thanks for trying to understand!